# Is the bracha of shecheyanu for buying new items said when buying medical equipment which he hopes he will never need to use?

Tags: halacha, blessing, shehecheyanu

Is the bracha of *shecheyanu* for buying new items (Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chayim 223:6; Mishnah Berurah 223:13) said when buying medical equipment which he hopes he will never need to use?

If someone buys an expensive piece of medical equipment, which will be life-saving to him if a specific medical situation arises, does he say the bracha of *shecheyanu* at the time of purchase? Do we say that since he is happy to have the equipment available for emergency use, he should say *shehecheyanu*, or do we say that since he hopes he will never have to make use of the equipment he does not say *shehecheyanu*?

Comment: Who wants a Yerusha to happen?

Comment: @DoubleAA the bracha is made only if it already happened! Im talking about making the bracha at time of purchase BEFORE anything happens.

Answer (score 1):

There is a certain amount of subjectivity in the bracha of *shecheyanu* in that the bracha is said if the object you buy brings you joy.

dinonline [writes](http://dinonline.org/2011/06/23/shehecheyanu-on-new-clothes-which-clothes/)

> Authorities dispute whether the berachah of shehecheyahu is entirely
>   subjective, depending on the subjective joy a person feels, or whether
>   the berachah includes an objective element, whereby if a garment or
>   item is not important, and does not usually induce joy, one cannot
>   recite the blessing. [...] Even if the item has some degree of
>   importance, such as a fancy shirt, it is sufficient for making the
>   blessing, **provided that the person experiences subjective joy in
>   buying it.**

R Chaim Cohen [here](https://doseofhalacha.blogspot.com/2014/08/bracha-on-new-car.html) writes

> The Shulchan Aruch (OC 223:6) and Mishna Berura (223:13) explain that
>   this only applies to items that are important **and one is particularly
>   happy about acquiring.**

Following the discussion in the comments, I found additional opinions supporting saying *shecheyanu* when experiencing mixed emotions, focusing the three weeks between 17 Tamuz and 9 Av. The following is extracted from the *sefer* Aveilut Hachurban by R Yoel Schwartz (from [here](http://www.ttidbits.com/1281/1281lite.pdf), p. 75)

- According to Shulchan Aruch and the Arizal, one should not say *shecheyanu* during the Three Weeks. **However**, one should not "spoil" the joy of a mitzva during this period of time by not saying the *bracha* -
  therefore at a *brit mila* or a *Pidyon HaBen* (even if they were postponed) the bracha is said. They also allow it for a (new) fruit that
  will not be available after Tish'a b'Av
- The Vilna Gaon holds that one need not refrain from *shecheyanu* during the Three Weeks

---

So if buying the medical equipment (like a heart defibrillator I assume) brings someone joy, he could say the bracha (there would be a secondary question of *shecheyanu* vs. *ha tov v' hameitiv* if the equipment can help others). If the worry of never having to make use of the equipment removes the joy completely, I do not think it is justified.

As always [CYLOR](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146) before attempting anything you read about here in real life.

Comment: ok so basiclly after all the information given the question still remains.  (1) There is subjectivity involved in the obligation to say Shecheyanu...  (2)The SA and MB pasken that if one is particularly happy about acquiring the item then he does say shehechyanu. (3) You would argue most people don't experience joy when buying such ... but this person is quite happy that now he has the life saving equipment necesary in case of emergency. Yet, (4) He hopes he will never have to make use of it. So, back to square one - Does he say Shecheyanu or not??  (Should I flag it as "not an answer"?)

Comment: subjectivity means it depends on how the person feels. **If the person feels real joy** (despite the fact others don't and despite the fact that he hopes never to have to use it,) **then he could say it**. I thought that is what my next to last para ("So if buying...") said

Comment: Do you have a source to that last part, particularly that "If the person feels real joy **despite the fact that he hopes never to have to use it** then he could say it"? after all that was the main point in my original question.

Comment: Let me break it down. The halacha says that someone feeling joy can/should say the bracha. I am personally feeling that, if you hope you never have to use it, you cannot feel joy because your joy is tempered by the anxiousness of not wanting to use it. But this is me. Maybe someone will feel pure joy and not be anxious not to use it. Since you wrote about "never having to use it", I felt maybe you felt like me. But maybe not. Someone who feels only joy falls within the halachic sources I quoted and should say it. I hope this clarifies my line of thought.

Comment: I was on the same page as you until the last sentence. You end with "someone who feels **only joy** falls within the halachic sources I quoted". If he feels great joy in finally having what he so desperately needs, yet he still hopes not to have to use it, is that joy neccesarilly "tempered by the anxiousness of not wanting to use it"? He may have untempered joy, yet it still does not fall under "feeling **only joy**. So which side tips the scales? Shechyanu or not?

Comment: My read of the sources is that he feels joy he could say it. We all have different feelings at the same time. One can be happy and hungry, happy about one thing and worried about another one, etc. That is what is hard with this "subjective" thing. If the person feels joy that he received the device, he could say it. That he also has other emotions in addition is not the issue. The issue is if he doesn't feel the joy because of the other emotions.

Comment: The whole idea of "only joy" and "tempered joy" is (lichora) disproven by a comment noted by DoubleAA that by yerusha one does say shecheyanu even though he doesnt feel only joy and untempered joy. Yet that is after the fact, Im discussing before, as I responded to his comment.

Comment: Exactly. We are now saying the same thing. Joy + other feelings = bracha. No joy because of other feelings = no bracha. I will edit to clarify.

Comment: As I ponted out, that only proves that if the object of the joy already exists then "other feelings" do not interefere. Yet, here the object of the joy is from an item which he hopes never to use. Joy from the purchase of an item is a direct result of his joy of its use., which in this case is questionable.

Comment: Perhaps an analogy would be a child gets his favorite toy for Chanukah. He experiences **only** joy. He really wanted it, and he is exhilarated that he got it, because he will play with it each day. Let's say that when his parents give him the toy they say, "We know that you wanted this toy so much. You can play with it, but you have to share it with your baby sister when you play with it, otherwise we'll take it away." So, he experiences joy at getting the toy, but, he's also annoyed that he has to share it.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore see my additions - maybe you will find this interesting